# pandas groupby via rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, database, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have a series of `news` and I want to group the `news` column by a rolling windows (for example, 3 days) to do further text analysis.

Note: the index may not be consecutive days (there might be some days with no entries).

The pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
        date      news
0    2017-01-03  'textA'
1    2017-01-03  'textB'
2    2017-01-04  'textC'
3    2017-01-05  'textD'
4    2017-01-05  'textE'
5    2017-01-05  'textF'
6    2017-01-06  'textG'
7    2017-01-06  'textH'
8    2017-01-07  'textI'
```

I want to iterate for all news using 3-day rolling window.
something like data.groupby('date', rolling = 3).apply(something) (I know there is no syntax like this, just for illustration purpose)

the first apply operation would apply on the following data (from 2017-01-03 to 2017-01-05).

```
2017-01-03  'textA'
2017-01-03  'textB'
2017-01-04  'textC'
2017-01-05  'textD'
2017-01-05  'textE'
2017-01-05  'textF'
```

Correspondingly, the second apply operation on this one:(from 2017-01-04 to 2017-01-06)

```
2017-01-04  'textC'
2017-01-05  'textD'
2017-01-05  'textE'
2017-01-05  'textF'
2017-01-06  'textG'
2017-01-06  'textH'
```

I know I can manually find the index and do the slicing. However I want if there is a more convenient way to do this using Python and Pandas features.

Comment: Your terminology is incorrect. It seems like you're taking 6 elements at a time in strides of 2. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, he takes window of 3 days and moves by a day every time.

Comment: Have you considered using `.between(date1, date1-datetime.timedelta(days=2))`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But where should I use the 'between'?

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` might help you: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html - see the `window` parameter part (new in 0.19.0): "If its an offset then this will be the time period of each window..."